# Is it possible to create a bar plot with data belonging to type "factor" in R programming?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SntyY.png)

The image consists of the data set which contains list of top 10 populated countries.so is it possible to create a barplot with country on x axis and Population on y axis where the data type i.e class of country values and population values is "factor".is it possible to plot this values on a bar plot.Can anyone help on the same.

Comment: Why are the population values a `factor`? It may be better to convert those to numeric. (looks like a file read problem noting the comma format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that what follows will be helpful for you.
Here is a dataset with the data of the top 10 populated countries:

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("China", "India", "United States", 
"Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh", "Russia", 
"Mexico"), Population = structure(c(3L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("130222815", "1342512706", "1388232693", 
"143375006", "164827718", "191835936", "196744376", "211243220", 
"263510146", "326474013"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Country", 
"Population"), row.names = 2:11, class = "data.frame")
```

The `df$Population` variable is a `factor` and the population values are stored in the factor levels:

```
str(df)   
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Country   : chr  "China" "India" "United States" "Indonesia" ...
 $ Population: Factor w/ 10 levels "130222815","1342512706",..: 3 2 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 1
```

We can plot the population values as follows.
First we convert the levels of `df$Population` into a numeric array:

```
Pop <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Population))
str(Pop)
num [1:10] 1388232693 1342512706 326474013 263510146 211243220 ...
```

and then we plot the population values using `barplot`:

```
par(mar=c(4,7,1,1))
options(scipen=9)
barplot(Pop, names=df$Country, yaxt = "n")
yticks <- pretty(Pop)
axis(2, yticks, las=2, labels = prettyNum(yticks, big.mark = ","))
```

[image]